# Vaccine for sheep pneumonia

Tags: medicines, vaccination, farm-animals, sheep

I have a clock of Chios sheep in the middle east region living in a semi-closed barn, pneumonia has been the major cause of death (in lambs) so far I have tried Tylosin and many Oxytetracycline antibiotics but it does not seem to go away from both the rams and ewes.

Is there an effective vaccine that could keep my sheep healthy?

Multiple vets diagnosed the problem as being pneumonia but just in case the symptoms are:

- Loud breath in ewes and rams.
- Ewes are not gaining weight.
- Loss of movement in the lambs across many days leading to death.
- Some Ewes do cough but it is not that common.

Comment: Not sure if this question is out of place but can't really find that many QA sites for this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should contact your vet for information and to get the vaccines administered to your sheep.

You can take a look here http://www.sheep101.info/201/vaccinations.html

there do exist atleast two types of pneumonia vaccines,your vet will know the type your sheep might need.

there might be other types of vaccines that your sheep will need that are spesific for your area/country.

Your best sources for information is often other sheep owners and the veterinarians in your area.

Your question is on topic here but my experience in farm animals is very limited,so your best option for information is your local vet.

Comment: I have spent hundreds of dollars on medications suggested by local farmers and multiple vets, it just seem acceptable to them to take the losses.

Comment: I would assume that sharing information over wide distances is an advantage :) But surely one need to calculate the risk caused by different environments, like climate and so on, before following blind eyed some (even good-minded) advice from the internet

Comment: @Allerleirauh Yah you do what you can, did a lot of studying before making the decision and the only thing I did not anticipate is willingness to send effort and money into a problem without being able to solve it. Anyway I believe in trial and error